# Insertar datos desde Visual Studio a SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Como puedo solucionar este problema al momento de insertar datos desde Visual Studio.net al SQL 
Este es mi codigo que utilice:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

Private Sub BtnInsertar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnInsertar.Click
    Dim conexion As SqlConnection
    conexion = New SqlConnection("server=USER-PC; database=base1; integrated security=true")
    conexion.Open()

    Dim placa As String = TxtPlaca.Text
    Dim marca As String = TxtMarca.Text
    Dim cilindraje As String = TxtCilindraje.Text
    Dim color As String = TxtColor.Text
    Dim modelo As String = TxtModelo.Text

    Dim cadena As String = "insert into automovil (placa, marca, cilindraje, color, modelo) values (" & placa & ",'" & marca & "', " & cilindraje & ",'" & color & "','" & modelo & "')"

    Dim comando As SqlCommand
    comando = New SqlCommand(cadena, conexion)
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MessageBox.Show("Datos Ingresados Correctamente")

    TxtPlaca.Text = ""
    TxtMarca.Text = ""
    TxtCilindraje.Text = ""
    TxtColor.Text = ""
    TxtModelo.Text = ""

    conexion.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Pero me detecta un error en la esta linea:

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

como puedo solucionarlo, soy principiante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es bastante claro, estas intentando insertar un valor explícito en la tabla `automovil` en una columna que no lo permite, posiblemente `placa`, por que la misma es del tipo [`IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186775(v=sql.120).aspx), lo que en español básico significa que es una columna auto-numérica, es decir, le corresponde al motor la actualización de la misma, no puedes explicitamente configurarle un valor. Lo que debes hacer es quitarla de la sentencia de `INSERT` y dejar que la base de dato se encargue de establecerle el valor. Si eventualmente necesitarás recuperar el valor de esta columna una vez insertada puedes utilizar la función [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190315(v=sql.120).aspx).

Obviamente si `placa` es el `IDENTITY` como imagino, en tu ejemplo debieras hacer esto:

```
Dim cadena As String = "insert into automovil (marca, cilindraje, color, modelo) values ('" & marca & "', " & cilindraje & ",'" & color & "','" & modelo & "')"
```

**Aclaración**: cuando digo que no puedes establecer el valor de esta columna en realidad debería decir que no es recomendable hacerlo en la mayoría de los casos, bajo ciertas circunstancias puedes hacer un `SET IDENTITY_INSERT automoviles ON;`, insertar el valor específico a la columna y volver todo a la normalidad con `SET IDENTITY_INSERT automoviles OFF;`, pero en tu ejemplo, no tiene ningún sentido hacerlo así.